# Why am I not eligible for the quest The Freightskippers?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have been questing with my Wife in SWTOR. We are both Republic. She is playing a Smuggler and I am a Trooper. We are both level 14. She is eligible for [The Freightskippers](http://www.torhead.com/mission/LQhHTk/the-freightskippers) from [Agent Nurls Yorksin](http://www.torhead.com/npc/dI3uhWo/agent-nurls-yorksin) on [Coruscant](http://www.torhead.com/area/1Sacyiw/coruscant). According to Torhead I, as a Trooper, should be eligible for the quest as well but it isn't letting me accept it (and it cannot be shared). The in game error message just says I am not eligible. I am pretty sure that the only quests that we have done differently are the class quests. Did I miss a prerequisite quest somehow? Torhead doesn't list any. Or is this a bug (and should I submit a ticket)?

Comment: Take ToRHead with a grain of salt. Their database remains woefully incomplete since they can't make a mod to help automate data collection like they did with WoW and WoWhead.

Comment: Yeah I hear that, but the quest isn't listed as a class quest and I haven't ran into any non-class quests yet that were not available to everyone. I might just submit a ticket and see what they say.

Comment: do you normally run as a group and were you grouped and not present when you wife grabbed the quest? Alternately, did your wife already start the mission and then group with you after? You should be eligible as that quest is just a bonus mission and the trouper we run with got it just fine.

Comment: The Starter planets are pretty much entirely non-class quests not available to everyone. Smuggler / Troopers can't get quests on Tython, and vice versa.

Comment: @sarge_smith I was in the group with my wife and was right next to her. The quest did not show up as available for me (the quest icon was not above the npc's head). This is not the first time this has happened to us, but the other times when one of us (that could see the quest) talked to the npc the other person (who couldn't see the quest) was automatically brought into the conversation, able to participate in the dialogue, and receive the quest. I will open a ticket up about it in the morning and see what a GM has to say about it.

Comment: @raven dreamer true but this is on Courscant, right outside the black sun area.

Comment: @adanion the group I run with have had some success with abandoning a quest and picking it back up from the beginning, but it has been extremely unreliable.  We've found that any that don't allow the entire party to participate at the time of initial encounter (meaning it doesn't give you the "a party member is about to start a conversation, would you like to holocall in" prompt) tend to bug, but dropping group and grabbing things individually is the most reliable way I know to fix it... and it both methods have like a twenty five percent success rate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get the quest finally. My HerpDerp moment was that my wife's Class Quest from the Old Market Guild was turned in at the Dealer's Den Cantina in the Old Galatic Market, while my Class Quest (Destroying the War Droids) was turned in at the Senate Tower. That meant that she was already on the new Class Quest to go to the Black Sun Territory and I wasn't, which is why the side quest for the Black Sun Territory wasn't available to me. We found Agent Nurls Yorksin on the way back to the Senate Tower.

Once I turned in my class quest and walked back down there the quest was available to me too. So there is a prerequisite quest for The Freightskippers and that is that you must be on your Class Quest for the Black Sun Territory, which in my case is called The Black Sun's Poison.

Comment: This appears to happen a lot, for a lot of quests. If you are playing with a close friend or significant other that is another class than you and one person is eligible for a quest and the other isn't... check that you are on the same area Class Quest. Chances are the person that can't see the quest is behind.